# MYSQL unique index using either of columns with same type of data

Tags: mysql

We have a table "Contact". It has following columns

```
id (PK), 
name, 
phone1, 
phone2, 
phone3, 
organization_id (fk)
```

It has an unique constraint on (phone1, organization_id)

I want to have constraint such that **(either of the columns phone1, phone2, phone3) and organization_id** should be unique.

For example 2 records like below should throw unique constraint violation error.

```
(phone1,phone2,phone3,org) values 
('100', null,  null,  20)
(null, '100',  null,  20)
```

I hope this is clear. TIA

Comment: better would be to have a contact table and a contact_phone table with a foreign key back to contacts, so each phone number is stored in one row, next to the ID of the contact. Then a) you can have as many or as few phone numbers for the contact as you please, and b) you can easily make a unique constraint as you need. I'm fairly sure what you're asking for above is impossible, but maybe someone with more expertise will contradict me.

Comment: Thanks. As far as I know this is not possible, but wanted to check. And yes creating link table is also another way to do it but I was trying to avoid the migration and changing a lot of java code.

Comment: @Saket Can two or three `phoneX` columns be set at the same time? How is the uniqueness defined in such a case?